# Can't add missing constraints Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have just finished an app which I will only be releasing on the iPhone, no iPads. Clearly there are different sized iPhones so I had to fix up a few layout issues in my project.

Apparently a nice way to approach this is to simply select the views and 'add missing constraints'.

When doing this I get the following error message:

[image]

I have tried clearing the constraints, but no look.

When I click 'reveal diagnostics in finder' I am directed to zip file named 'IB-layout-diagnostics_2015-07-08_13-57-41_336000' containing log files and simply can't decrypt it.

Has it something to do with the fact that I have the app completed, and am accessing some of the views programatically in Swift?

In the development info I have the device set to iPhone, the device orientation to Portrait, and I have 'Use Auto Layout' and 'Size Classes' checked.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the constraints manually (ex: ctrl + drag)?

Comment: Never heard of this, sounds interesting

Comment: Please file a bug and attach the zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may not be specific enough. But if anyone else is having the same problem this is the solution I found:

- Copy all views from inside the Table View Cell, into some other temporary View Controller
- Delete all views from Table View Cell
- Select all Views in Controller and add missing constraints (Works now!)
- Add views back to Table View Cell

If anyone has an alternative solution which can be explained to me, feel free to answer or edit this one. Thanks.